# Remove indent from left in antd tree

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I need your help to solve this problem.

I am using the Ant Design tree and when I expand a tree node an indent of 24px is added. I want to remove this indentation and set it to 0px. Not able to figure out the CSS changes for this.

`.ant-tree-indent-unit { display: inline-block; width: 24px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
.ant-tree-indent { 
   display: none
}
```

would work